# How to introduce a make dependency on git commit?

Tags: git, makefile, git-commit

I've made a little script that generates a header that has git commit information for my repository that I can include in my source to see what version of the code I am using.  Example:

```
#if !defined physicsplay_build_version_h_is_included
#define physicsplay_build_version_h_is_included

#define PHYSICSPLAY_COMMIT_INFO "Revision https://github.com/peeterjoot/physicsplay commit d771eeced6552643b3f08c8f87286494189a72a8 Feb/29/2016"

#endif
```

I'd like to write a make rule to regenerate this file if I've done a new commit.  I tried using .git/index as a dependency in my makefile for this header, but this gets updated after 'git status' and probably other things.

What's the best way to introduce a make dependency of this sort?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to write a make rule to regenerate this file if I've done a new commit

Use hooks: `pre-commit` or `pre-recive`

#### `hook sample`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Check to see if this is the first commit in the repository or not
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # We compare our changes against the previous commit
    against=HEAD^
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# Redirect output to screen.
exec 1>&2

# Check and do what ever you want to do here
if [ ...  ];
then

    # personal touch :-)
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
    echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
    echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
    echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
    echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
    echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
    echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
    echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
    echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
    echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
    echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
    echo "                                         "
fi;

# set the exit code to 0 or 1 based upon your needs
# 0 = good to push
# 1 = exit without pushing.
exit 0;
```

Comment: I'd go for the post-commit/receive hooks myself, other than that my answer would be "what codeWizard said"

Comment: Just choose your hook, it can be any hook since you don't modify the content